# How to extract a url from a webpage?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Twitter returns a webpage that these lines are among others:

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//video.twimg.com" />
<link rel="preload" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://ma-0.twimg.com/twitter-assets/responsive-web/web/ltr/vendor.69f9ac19fa493004.js" />
<link rel="preload" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://ma-0.twimg.com/twitter-assets/responsive-web/web/ltr/i18n/en.312d3f56908013c9.js" />
<link rel="preload" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://ma-0.twimg.com/twitter-assets/responsive-web/web/ltr/main.da8c0a0fbf03fdac.js" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="2231777543" />
```

I need the url that contains the `main.*.js` file. How can I get it?

I tried this:

```
var mainIndex = content.IndexOf("main.");
var startIndex = content.LastIndexOf("href=\"", mainIndex) + 6;
var endIndex = content.IndexOf(".js", startIndex) + 3;
var url = content.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

but it's a bad unsafe implementation. Thanks.

Comment: Use regex (regular expressions).

Comment: Never,Never Never use Regex to parse a webpage.  Very bad suggestion.  It is ok to use regex on substrings extracted from html.  You should be using GetElementsByTagName("link") then extracting the attributes href which returns a string.

Comment: Also relephant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2546433

Comment: @ErikBožič Thanks for that :))

Comment: Do not use regex, see the HtmlAgilityPack-related answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a dedicated HTML parser, such as [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

```
var text = "<link rel=\"dns-prefetch\" href=\"//vide.... />";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(text);

var links = doc
    .DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//link")
    .Select(e=>e.Attributes["href"].Value);

links
    // here, you could parse and match the URL robustly
    .Where(href=>href.Contains("main"))
    // try it in LINQPad
    .Dump();
```

result: `https://ma-0.twimg.com/twitter-assets/responsive-web/web/ltr/main.da8c0a0fbf03fdac.js`

Comment: Thanks @dmitryLedentsov .. I try it now

Comment: sorry it doesn't have a '.SelectNodes' method.. am I missing a using directive?

Comment: @Blendester yes, you need a `using HtmlAgilityPack;` line. Did you install it via Nuget?

Comment: yes I did using NuGet .. also added using HtmlAgilityPack.. it's inside a class library

Comment: but says `SelectNodes` doesn't exist. isn't any other way to select nodes?

Comment: version: 1.4.9.5. It's a well-documented C# library: what does the IntelliSense/disassembly show you, what the available methods are?

Comment: `SelectNodes` is event part of the official samples http://html-agility-pack.net/ . Please check your build configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146065/discussion-between-dmitry-ledentsov-and-blendester).

Answer (score -3):

it is definitely a good idea to use regex for it.
first one regex for the prefix part that should be replaced with empty string and same thing for end.
you will need to escape the chars like < with \< and to use the normal regex syntax to exactly define what is required.